# update the first character of line if line contains two strings

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am looking for a script to search a line if it contains two strings and then find if the first charater of that line contains certain character and remove it.

Eg. if line contains two strings as "abc" and "xyz" it should look for first character of the line and if it contains # , it should remove it and vice-versa.

It tried to run below command in crontab and got the result

```
crontab -l | grep az2-er32-cxv-iz| grep aze
```

Output

```
#5,10 * * * * /opt/apps/scripts/dsm-rync -q -del -s az2-er32-cxv-iz /opt/apps/sdl/scripts/aze-dsm-rync.app.config
```

since , its difficult to update the crontab entry directly , i copied it to `tmpfile`.

`crontab -l > tmpfile`  and tried to run `sed 's/^#//' tmpfile` but it is removing all `#` instead of the line matching with two strings

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Please post real input (sanitized if needed), and a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with real output. Please let me know if i need to add anything else

Answer (score 1):

You may use `gnu awk` to do this easily:

```
awk -i inplace '/az2-er32-cxv-iz/ && /aze/{sub(/^#/, "")} 1' crontab
```

This will remove `#` from first position if line has `az2-er32-cxv-iz` and `aze` in it.

Comment: Thanks , it is giving the exact output on stdout but not updating the crontab entry when I check crontab entry. How can we update it at the same time

Comment: What is your awk version?

Comment: awk -W version returned below.                                                                GNU Awk 4.2.1 , API : 2.0 ( GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: To store the awk as your crontab, assuming your shell is bash: `crontab <(awk '...')` -- read your crontab(1) man page.

Comment: @pandeg: Check updated answer or follow Glenn's helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Shloim, I won't give you the code itself, but I'm giving you a piece of pseudo-code to start:

- In order to know if a line contains at least two words, you might search for a space within that line. (`grep " " <filename>`)
- In order to know if a line starts with a certain character, you might search for the  character, followed by that one certain character. (`grep "<beginning_of_line>#"`)
- Replacing a character in a line can be done, using the `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks I tried to use the below sed command to replace the first character  # with empty for the matching string in line  but it is not returning the desired output                                                                                          sed '/az2-er32-cxv-iz\|aze/s/^#//' tmpfile